# Matching in mongo inside aggregate doesn't return result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
db.company_name_match.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": {"link": "$link", "company_name": "$company_name", "city": "$city"}, res: {$sum: 1}}},{$match: {res: {$gt: 1}}}])
```

This is meant to find duplicates in the collection. 
However, when I add to the match stage another condition, the query doesn't return any results.

```
db.company_name_match.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": {"link": "$link", "company_name": "$company_name", "city": "$city"}, res: {$sum: 1}}}, {$match: {res: {$gt: 1}, match_count: 0}}])
```

Am I doing something wrong here? And I am positive that there are documents which have the match_count == 0.

Comment: Because you are not returning a field called "match_count" of course. 'Pipeline" means that the only **input** for a given stage is the **output** of the previous stage. Since your `$group` does not emit this field, you cannot match a condition on it.

Comment: I think I've tried that too. Do you mean I would add to $group the field match_count: $match_count ?

Comment: I mean you need to add a `match_count: { $first: "$match_count" }` into the accumulated fields output by `$group`, or at least something like that. It's unclear if you expect this field to have the same value in the "duplicates" or not. But you basically need to use one of the accumulator operators in order to return a value so it is visible.

Comment: $match applies an AND operation, so make sure that those documents with "match_count:0" are also "res: {$gt: 1}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Neil Lunn suggested I've fixed this by adding the field to the group aggregation pipeline stage.
As a result, I've got the following query:

```
db.company_name_match.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": {"link": "$link", "company_name": "$company_name", "city": "$city"}, match_results: {$first: "$match_results"}, res: {$sum: 1}}},{$match: {res: {$gt: 1}, match_results:[]}}])
```